# Hessian matrix of $(||x||-b)^2$

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

I want to calculate the Hessian matrix of $(||x||-b)^2$ wrt $x$, where $||*||$ is the L2 norm and $x$ is a vector. I know how to calculate the first-order derivative: 
$dV = 2(1 - \frac{b}{||x||})x^Tdx$, but I don't know how to calculte $d^2V$ and get the Hessian matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
$Let's use a convention wherein matrices, vectors, and scalars are represented by uppercase latin, lowercase latin, and greek letters, respectively.

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{\
\beta &= b \\
\lambda^2 &= \|x\|^2 = x^Tx \quad\implies\quad \lambda\,\c{d\lambda} = x^Tdx \\
}$$
Write the objective function in terms of these variables, then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{\
 \phi &= (\lambda-\beta)^2 \\
d\phi &= 2(\lambda-\beta)\;\c{d\lambda} \\
  &= \frac{2(\lambda-\beta)\;\c{x^Tdx}}{\c{\lambda}} \\
g=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}
 &= \frac{2(\lambda-\beta)\,x}{\lambda} \\
}$$
Now calculate differential and gradient of $g$, i.e. the Hessian.
$$\eqalign{
dg
 &= \frac{2(\lambda-\beta)\;dx}{\lambda}
  + \frac{2\;\c{d\lambda}\;x}{\lambda}
  - \frac{2(\lambda-\beta)x\;\c{d\lambda}}{\lambda^2} 
\\
 &= \frac{2(\lambda-\beta)\,I\,dx}{\lambda}
  + \frac{2x(\c{x^Tdx})}{\lambda\c{\lambda}}
  - \frac{2(\lambda-\beta)x(\c{x^Tdx})}{\lambda^2\c{\lambda}} 
\\
 &= \left(\frac{2\lambda^2(\lambda-\beta)I + \g{2\lambda xx^T} - \g{2}{(\g{\lambda}-\beta)\g{xx^T}}}{\lambda^{3}}\right) dx 
\\
 &= \left(\frac{2\lambda^2(\lambda-\beta)I + 2\beta xx^T}{\lambda^3}\right)dx \\
\\
H=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
&=\left(\frac{2\lambda^2(\lambda-\beta)I+2\beta xx^T}{\lambda^3}\right) \\
&= 2I + \frac{2\beta}{\|x\|}\left(\frac{xx^T}{\|x\|^2}-I\right) \\
}$$